# Why does the Identity Server 4 demo use an iframe for back channel logout

Tags: identityserver4

The example IS4 host app ([LoggedOut.cshtml](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/host/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml)) uses an iframe for both front ánd back channel logout. The [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html) also says that both flows are implemented via an iframe.

However, if I'm looking at the [source code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/Infrastructure/BackChannelLogoutClient.cs), I don't really understand why it must use an iframe for back channel logout. It looks possible to just do back channel logout in code, and without any iframes.

Comment: FYI - I did back channel logout in plain code now, without any iframe, and it just works. Create the logout_token (see IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.BackChannelLogoutClient) and post it to the client.

Comment: the back channel logout can be used even in clients with no front channel, think in devices others than computers, tablets or smartphones. Please check this link to official identity server documentation: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html